# mysqldump on percona 8

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I have a production server running on AWS EC2 with GP2 SSD disk, it is working fine without any problems, but I noticed something weird, when I dump a database first time I take the dump it take longer than when I repeat the dump,

first dump for 22MB data take

real    0m48.601s
user    0m7.156s
sys     0m0.636s
and when I repeat the dump it take

real    0m9.723s
user    0m7.025s
sys     0m0.456s
what is the explain for this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Caching (less I/O needed the second time)

I expect that the 3rd time will again be about 0m9.723s.